# How to make a feature introduced in one branch merge into other branches?

Tags: git

Sorry for the bad English, let me explain with a simplified example.

Say I have a `master` branch, and a `asdf` file with contents:

```
master
```

Then I created `v1` branch from `master`, and add some `v1` stuff

```
git checkout -b v1
echo "v1" >> asdf
git commit -am"v1"
```

Then create `v2` from `v1`, and add some `v2` only stuff

```
git checkout -b v2
echo "v2-only" >> asdf
git commit -am"v2-only"
```

Then add some stuff to `v2` which should be added to `v1` and `master` also

```
echo "common" >> asdf
git commit -am"add common in v2"
```

Now, question, how can I make these changes to `v1` and `master`?

If I checkout v1 and merge v2, the `v2-only` stuff is also merged, which is not I want.

This is a simple example, the real world question is we have a base source code, and created many vendor-specific branches with vendor-specific features from that base code. How can we make a feature introduced in `branch01` which have many commits merge into other branches?

Comment: Your options are basically merging/rebasing or doing a cherry-pick.  What design decision led to the situation where you need to cross-pollinate vendor branches like this?  I would think it better that common features to some/all vendors should exist in the `master` branch or another common branch.

Comment: Your English is fine and your example is very easy to understand. I would only suggest that you replace "staff" with "stuff"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Our products serves many customers, basically one customer one branch and one team. some team may find bugs or add new features can be used in other branches.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks, updated

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options.

First, if this just happend and `add common in v2` is the last commit on `v2`, the easiest thing to do is just to reset the commit,

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

You can add `--soft` to keep the changes staged

```
git reset HEAD~1 --soft
```

checkout the branch where you want these changes

```
git checkout master
```

And make a new commit. But keep in mind that you will have to rewrite the commit message.

As a Bonus, if you then want to have to commit back on `v1` and `v2` again, use rebase.

```
git checkout v1
git rebase master
git checkout v2
git rebase master
```

---

Now if the commit is not the last commit you will need to cherry pick it. To do this you need the SHA of the commit. There are different ways to get this, but lets go with git log here.

```
git log
```

The SHA is the long number for each commit.

Now, checkout master.

```
git checkout master
```

And cherry pick the commit.

```
git cherry-pick (your-sha)
```

Cherry picking does not remove the commit form branch `v2`. If you want this, you will need to look into `git rebase -i`, but this is its own monster.